# Comprobar si el valor de una lista se encuentra en el Data Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

¿Cómo están? Espero que muy bien
Tengo un problema con un Data Frame
mi idea es ver qué valores de una lista están en el df. Si se encuentra, agregar en la columna 3 de este df un 1, si no se encuentra un 0.

Ejemplo
df=

```
     A      B  
0  rar    csa  
1  eur    dee  
3  bar    esa  
6  foo    dsd  
7  foo    aaa
```

luego tengo la siguiente lista=['iia','rar','lan','foo','air']
y me gustaría que todos los valores de esta lista que se encuentran en la columna A del dataframe (df ['A']) sean aclarados en una una tercera columna "C" con 0 (si no se encuentra) y 1 (si se encuentra ). Quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
     A      B  C
0  rar    csa  1
1  eur    dee  0
3  bar    esa  0
6  foo    dsd  1
7  foo    aaa  1
```

el código que se me ocurrió fue un for (de hecho convertí la lista en otro df)... pero esto tarda muchisimo en recorrer toda la lista (son mas de 18mil datos) estoy seguro que tiene que haber una manera mas rápida. Saludos

```
cuento=0
df[3]=0
for i in df[0]:
    for e in df2[0]:
        if str(i) == str(e):
            df[3][cuento]="1"
        else:
            df[3][cuento]="0"
    cuento=cuento+1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un bucle es siempre la peor forma de usar pandas, pues pandas tiene funciones "vectorizadas" que actúan "a la vez" (es una forma de hablar) sobre todos los valores de una columna o de un dataframe. En realidad no actúan a la vez, obviamente, internamente pandas hace un bucle, pero hay una diferencia abismal en el rendimiento entre dejar que sea pandas quien internamente haga el bucle o hacerlo tú con python. Ello se debe a que buena parte de pandas descansa en numpy, que está implementado en C y altamente optimizado.

Dicho esto, para tu caso pandas tiene una función que sería `pandas.Series.isin()` que permite precisamente verificar si cada elemento de una Serie (una columna) está o no en una lista que le pases como parámetro, así:

```
df.A.isin(lista)
```

el resultado es otr Serie de booleanos, con True o False según el elemento esté o no en la lista. Si lo que quieres son ceros y unos, puedes convertir el booleano a entero, por ejemplo sumándole `0`. Esto puede hacerse también en forma vectorizada, sin iterar, sumando 0 a la columna completa.

Así pues, la solución completa para tu caso se resuelve con dos líneas:

```
lista=['iia','rar','lan','foo','air']
df["C"] = df.A.isin(lista)+0
```

El resultado en tu caso sale:

```
     A    B  C
0  rar  csa  1
1  eur  dee  0
3  bar  esa  0
6  foo  dsd  1
7  foo  aaa  1
```

Si no te gusta el "hack" de sumar 0, puedes también convertir el booleano en entero así:

```
df.A.isin(lista).astype(int)
```

**Nota**. Por curiosidad me gustaría que indicaras en un comentario la diferencia en el tiempo de ejecución entre tu solución mediante bucles y esta otra solución vectorizada.

Comment: muy bueno , la verdad no entendí como funciono el +0, me lo podrías explicar ? de verdad que me gusto mucho ese  "hack" jajaja

Comment: Bueno, cuando intentas operar con un booleano en un contexto de una operación matemática (suma, multiplicación, etc..) en ese momento Python lo convierte a entero para poder hacer la operación, y convierte True en 1 y False en 0. Al sumarles 0 no cambian su valor. Otro ejemplo, si haces `booleano*2`, el resultado sería 0 si el booleano era `False`, o será 2 (1*2) si el booleano era `True`.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo usando una función lambda, así:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ['rar', 'eur', 'bar','foo','foo'], 'B': ['csa', 'dee', 'esa','dss','aaa']})

lista = ['iia', 'rar', 'lan', 'foo', 'air']

df['C']= df['A'].apply(lambda x: 1 if (x in lista) else 0)
print(df)
```

En este caso, la función `lambda` está evaluando la condición `if` para cada `x` (cada valor en `df['A']`) y retorna `1` si es verdadero, `0` si es falso.

Bienvenido a StackOverflow.

Comment: Te dejo aquí un enlace con explicación y ejemplo de [funciones lambda](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/funciones-lambda/)